# Facebook page like automatically after the user login

Tags: javascript, html

I want to like facebook page automatically after the user login.but am also want the page not dislike after again login the user.

Am using this code:

Comment: I think you can't auto like & dislike, it's against Facebook rules.

Comment: Am using this script

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  var interval = 0;

  function updateActiveElement() {
    if($(document.activeElement).attr('id') == "fb-iframe") {
      clearInterval(interval);
      bodyClicked = true;
   jQuery('#iframe-wrapper').remove();
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    interval = setInterval(updateActiveElement(), 50);
  });

</script>

Comment: This is working on all body but I want like on facebook login only